# Can't convert string into Json object

Tags: json, swift, swift2, swifty-json

I have a json string (`text2`):

> "{\"MsgType\":103,\"Msg\":\"{\"UserObject\":{\"SecretId\":\"dsofgihsdaoifhad=\",\"FirstName\":\"ASDGF\",\"LastName\":\"hdsa\",\"IsFemale\":0,\"PhoneOffice\":\"\",\"ISDCode\":\"\",\"PhonePersonal\":\"91923426989\",\"Designation\":\"\",\"Company\":\"\",\"TagLine\":\"helping
>   mplemented\",\"FbId\":\"\",\"FbURL\":\"\",\"FbToken\":\"\",\"GplusId\":\"\",\"GplusURL\":\"\",\"GplusToken\":\"\",\"LinkedinId\":\"\",\"LinkedinURL\":\"\",\"LinkedinToken\":\"\",\"Status\":\"\",\"Email\":\"\",\"DisplayPicture\":\"\",\"IsPrivatePhoneOffice\":0,\"IsPrivatePhonePersonal\":1,\"IsPrivateEmail\":0,\"DeviceType\":\"android\",\"NotificationRegistrationID\":\"APA9HZ_RmEy7gfbQtN-QBxXr7dafG394oT9Dg1HpAv7OaWbUsMOsfpMI1a_7Qa2aNkqBOWB3M29djtsRW0fWl4oZSG0bwVv1zEPDBAseZvv1eHfqVj_JUI8tZixX\",\"Location\":\"\",\"Latitude\":18.69943,\"Longitude\":77.12576,\"IsPrivate\":0},\"ConnectionStatus\":3,\"ConnectionType\":1,\"PreviousMeetings\":[{\"SecretId\":\"sadfosdfjasdf=\",\"FriendSecretId\":\"dsofgihsdaoifhad=\",\"MeetingTime\":1447088420440,\"Status\":\"\",\"MeetingNotes\":\"\",\"Location\":\"\",\"Latitude\":28.6994,\"Longitude\":77.1258,\"ContactType\":\"\"},{\"SecretId\":\"sadfosdfjasdf=\",\"FriendSecretId\":\"dsofgihsdaoifhad=\",\"MeetingTime\":1447088335275,\"Status\":\"\",\"MeetingNotes\":\"\",\"Location\":\"\",\"Latitude\":28.6994,\"Longitude\":77.1258,\"ContactType\":\"\"},{\"SecretId\":\"sadfosdfjasdf=\",\"FriendSecretId\":\"dsofgihsdaoifhad=\",\"MeetingTime\":1447088229120,\"Status\":\"\",\"MeetingNotes\":\"\",\"Location\":\"\",\"Latitude\":28.6994,\"Longitude\":77.1258,\"ContactType\":\"\"},{\"SecretId\":\"sadfosdfjasdf=\",\"FriendSecretId\":\"dsofgihsdaoifhad=\",\"MeetingTime\":1447088014838,\"Status\":\"\",\"MeetingNotes\":\"\",\"Location\":\"\",\"Latitude\":28.6994,\"Longitude\":77.1258,\"ContactType\":\"\"},{\"SecretId\":\"sadfosdfjasdf=\",\"FriendSecretId\":\"dsofgihsdaoifhad=\",\"MeetingTime\":1444547028931,\"Status\":\"\",\"MeetingNotes\":\"\",\"Location\":\"\",\"Latitude\":28.6994,\"Longitude\":77.1258,\"ContactType\":\"\"}]}\"}"

It contains a json object having 2 fields: `MsgType` and `Msg`. `Msg` further containes a serialized json object in form of string.

I need to read the value of `MsgType` as number and `Msg` as a json object.

I have tried couple of things:

Firstly:

```
  if let dataFromString = text2.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {
                                let json = JSON(data: dataFromString)
                                print("swiftyjson:\(json)")
                            }
```

Source: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#initialization

Output:

> swiftyjson:null

Secondly:

```
let data = text2.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!

                            do {
                                let jsonSys = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [])
                                print("jsonSys:\(jsonSys)")
                            } catch let error as NSError {
                                print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                            }
```

Output:

> Failed to load: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the
>   correct format.

Comment: Why is your code intended so strangely? The least you can do is format your question properly so that it is readable.

Comment: print `error` rather than `error.localizedDescription` this gives you the location where the text is improperly formatted.

Comment: PS: as far as I can see there are a lot of superfluous double quotes in the text

Comment: @vadian: here is the error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Badly formed object around character 24." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Badly formed object around character 24.}

Comment: Character 24 is the double quote right before `{\"UserObject` as Eric mentioned.

Comment: The answer from @eric-d is the correct answer. By the way you can check this by yourself next time with a JSON validator like [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/). And be sure to use `print(text2)` to log your JSON properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON string is not properly escaped.

- The "Msg" opening dictionary `{` shouldn't be preceded by a double quote, it should be like this:

> "{\"MsgType\":103,\"Msg\":{\"UserObject\" ...

- Same error at the end, it should be:

> ... 77.1258,\"ContactType\":\"\"}]}}"